# Cannot get variables from Windows activation through Wmic SoftwareLicensingProduct

Tags: windows, wmic, licensing

I'm trying to get Windows 10 Licensing Informations through WMIC SoftwareLicensingProduct reading in a loop but it displays nothing...
The command line itself produces the right information in a CMD box :

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE "(Name LIKE '%%Windows%%') AND (PartialProductKey is not null)" get Description, LicenseStatus, Name, PartialProductKey /format:list
```

As :

```
Description=Windows(R) Operating System, RETAIL channel
LicenseStatus=1
Name=Windows(R), Professional edition
PartialProductKey=....
```

But the command line inserted in a loop as follow, doesn't produce anything (tried with one variable at first)...

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "WPath=%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe"
for /f "usebackq tokens=4 delims==" %%i in ('%WPath% PATH SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE "(Name LIKE '%%Windows%%') AND (PartialProductKey is not null)" get Description, LicenseStatus, Name, PartialProductKey /format:list') do set _variable=%%i
@echo !_variable!
```

Comment: Why are you trying to retrieve the license code? What underlying problem are you trying to solve? Wouldn’t expect your code to work on anything but OEM hardware

Comment: @Ramhound : I'm not trying to retrieve the license code, I'm just trying to retrieve the Windows version (Pro/Educ/...) and licensing status (licensed, grace,...) on laptop being installed to know if OS as already been activated or not and skip one configuration step on school refurbished laptops. (I know perfectly well how to retrieve the license code stored in BIOS...)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be under the impression that the `for` command with
"usebackq tokens=4" will work on the fourth line, but it will work instead
on each line, setting `_variable` to the fourth token on the last line,
which would be empty.

To operate on the right line, use the command

```
wmic ... | findstr PartialProductKey
```

The token to search would be the second one.

Comment: thanks but PartialProductKey is not what I'm interested in : I use it as a filter so that both items containing "Windows" AND where "PartialProductKey" is not empty are displayed ; otherwise you get a huge list of products with License=0, or licensed products like MS Office...
I want to retrieve which Windows OS licensed product is installed, name (Pro/Educ/other), status (activated or else) partial key (to manage the OS keys me bought to Microsoft)

Comment: If you're interested only in the first line, use `findstr Description`. You would also need `delims==,` and it will be the third token.